# Multiple ADD statements for an ALTER statement

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to do something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE mbk_user
    ADD uuid varchar NOT NULL,
    ADD email varchar NOT NULL,
    ADD handle varchar NOT NULL;
```

but this doesnt seem to valid, I have to do this instead?

```
ALTER TABLE mbk_user
    ADD uuid varchar NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE mbk_user
    ADD email varchar NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE mbk_user
    ADD handle varchar NOT NULL;
```

is there a workaround?

Comment: Your statement works fine on my PostgreSQL v13 database.

Comment: youre talking about the first statement right?

Comment: *but this doesnt seem to valid* Do you receive some error message? provide its text, complete and unchanged.

Comment: Yes, the first statement that you claim to fail works fine.